# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache') when trying to get a random users avatar Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, typeerror

This code gets displays a random user's avatar when you type !avatar, but it does not work and only returns TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'avatar',
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     */
    description: "Get avatar",
    async execute(client, args, message,){
        const user = client.users.cache.random()

        message.channel.send(
            new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL())
        )
    }

}
```

I changed module.exports to module.exports.execute

Comment: What version of DiscordJS are you using? Also, what happens if you just console.log('client', client) at the top of your execute function?

Comment: `random()` is not a method in `client.users.cache...`, it's only a `GuildMemberManager` feature

Comment: @jnchaba I have v13, and when it comes to console.log('client', client) at the top of the execute function I get ReferenceError: client is not defined in the console

Comment: can you access client from the message object? `message.client` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing this code line:

```
const user = client.users.cache.random()
```

to:

```
const user = message.guild.members.cache.random()
```

because you only need to `cache` on your main server or whenever the bot gets in

Comment: I tried changing it to what you have told me and now I get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guild')

Comment: Can I see your intents? Edit your post with `index.js` or might be `bot.js`

Comment: plus it sometime about your `executing` wrong, it should be `client, message, args`